# Microsoft Excel - How to transform a vertical list with doubled ID to an horizontal one without duplication

Tags: excel, list, matrix, binary, duplication

I have a list in excel like this:

```
Case ID Name
65003   value1
65003   value2
65003   value3
65003   value2
65004   value1
65004   value1
65005   value6
65006   value7
65006   value1
```

I want to delete duplication and to get a list like this:

```
Case ID value1  value2  value3  value4  value5  value6  value7
65003   1       1       1       0       0       0       0
65004   1       0       0       0       0       0       0
65005   0       0       0       0       0       1       0
65006   1       0       0       0       0       0       1
```

How can I do it please?

Thank you :)

Comment: Voted to close becasue Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @mehow He's not asking for code, his question is more suited to superuser.

Comment: @bendataclear try solving it with no VBA ;)

Comment: `65003 value2` is repeated. Do you intend it to result in 1 or 2?

Answer (score 2):

Can be solved with no VBA:

Add column in row C with just `1` in all cells.

Highlight range and select Insert > Pivottable

In Pivot table add ID's to row headers, values to column headers and MAX of the number column in the values, gives the result:

[image]

If you wantto show values with no results you can you just need a list of them in another range.